# How to calculate this permutation?

Tags: statistics

How many ways can UNC, Duke and Florida State finish 1-2-3 in the AAC regular season rankings?

Please show work. Thank you.

Comment: Please, could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry thats all I have. The teacher didn't specify anything else

Comment: But can not you explain by yourself? You should know the aim of the exercise before trying to solve it or even ask for help.

Comment: I searched. I am sorry. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lack of more information, we assume that the 1-2-3 ranking pertains to the three teams: UNC, Duke, and Florida State

Here we compute  number of [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of three objects. There are three possible choices for first place; then there are only two possible choices left for second place (since one team must have finished first). Finally, we are left with only one choice for the third place (the one team that didn't place first or second). These choices are multiplied to compute the total number of possible rankings: $$3\times 2\times 1 = 3!=6$$

Comment: Thats the answer I got. My teacher said the answer is 9. I don't know how.

Comment: Your teacher is incorrect!  There is no logic to an answer of "$9$"!

Comment: Thanks. Can you please try solving my standard deviation and variance problems? I have absolutely no clue how to do them and my teacher is no good.